# Trigger send emails from SF CRM vs, SFMC

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, email, json

Situation is having a SF CRM in place where a JSON call is kept at the lead/contact level. This JSON is requested by a CMS to change a website.

When triggering an email of the SFMC Contact or Lead data is pushed to the SFMC. We can't designate fields or anything even though it's not used within the email personalization. In essence the trigger just throws all the fields at the SFMC and it's up to the SFMC to figure out what to do with the data.

This wouldn't be a problem if it wouldn't contain a JSON script in there. Because this creates a JSON within a JSON which isn't working. There's no possibility to block the field at this moment and we can't change the JSON with some kind of a delimiter because than it wouldn't work with the CMS of the website.

So we need to find a way not to send the JSON field?

Any directions, ideas…?

Comment: Is that field mapped on the SFMC side?  If you go to the Marketing Cloud > Email > Subscribers > Profile Management > Click into a profile attribute > Select Salesforce tab you can see if that field is mapped to SF CRM.  It should only be pushing over mapped fields so if that field isn't used then unmapping it should solve the issue.